# Reset a sharedpreference at a specified time with alarmmanager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, counter, reset

I have two counters stored with sharedpreferences and I need to reset them to zero everyday at midnight, I know I have to use alarmmanager but I don't really know how I have to do it, I looked at SO exemples and on the google documentation but  can't find a way to do it.

the two counters I have are stored like this:

`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = counters.edit();
 editor.putInt("wcounter", wcounter);
 editor.commit();`

how can I reset them at midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the alarm somewhere appropriate in your code:

```
private void schedAlarm(Context context) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstace();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, YourBroadcastReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24, pi);
}
```

Add `YourBroadcastReceiver` as class and in AndroidManifest.
In `YourBroadcastReceiver`:

```
public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        .edit().remove("wcounter").commit();
}
```

Comment: I have to put the broadcast in the Manifest?? or is it in the .java?

Comment: Both. You need to add the Java class and register it in your AndroidManifest to announce it to the system. It's like and Activity, but different purpose.

Comment: I can't find anywhere how to put the second part of the code you wrote in the manifest... :/

Comment: Don't put java code into the xml, you need to register the receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml. Please reade some basic documentation about Android development on http://d.android.com

Comment: So I pasted your code at the appropriate placesbut I still have three errors: 

cal.add(Calendar.DAY, 1); here I have DAY cannot be resolved or is not a field ; 

I don't know how to change this to : YourBroadcastReceiver.class ;

and on this "Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)" I have this error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Context

Comment: I made the two trivial fixes. BTW: you should try to understand the code, not just copy it. If you really want to get your app done, you should learn how to fix these things yourself.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, I'm really new to this and I'm trying as hard as I can to make heads and tails of all this code (I come from the web dev). But I can't understand what YourBroadcastReceiver refers to, and why schedAlarm is not used anywhere