# Delete SharedPreferences

Tags: android

How can I delete values of SharedPreferences every day at midnight?

Comment: Set an alarm at 11:55 PM to wake you up so you can delete them on time. :0

Comment: Looks like an interview question :)

Comment: What did you try, if anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `AlarmManager` that runs everyday at midnight, then deletes the values that you want. Here you are a tutorial on the alarm
http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AlarmManager to start an event at midnight. In alarm manager set a repeating alarm for every midnight. There is a similar question in so. [Reset a sharedpreference at a specified time with alarmmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671714/reset-a-sharedpreference-at-a-specified-time-with-alarmmanager)
 If you make some edits you will have the required code.